# Display values from different datasets based on conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Thanks for reading my question!

I have two different datasets, each in a different sheet, as below:

1st table: Sales data from survey (less correct):

| Client | Yearly Sales |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 10 |
| Google | 20 |
| Nestle | 50 |

2nd table: Sales data from accounting (correct data):

| Client | Yearly Sales |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 11 |
| Google | 20 |
| Mercedes | 30 |

Now, I have to make a summary report of these two. The rules are:

1. Each client from both lists must be included (I have accomplished this already; Column "Client");
2. I must include Yearly Sales; **if the data from 2nd table is different from the 1st, the data in 2nd table is included**;
3. I'm trying to accomplish this in a spilled range ("Client" is a spilled range);
4. There are unique client names in each table (they are all included in my summary report);
5. I'm trying to accomplish this without VBA code.

The summary report must look like this:

| Client | Yearly Sales |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 11 |
| Google | 20 |
| Mercedes | 30 |
| Nestle | 50 |

Note: I've tried using XLOOKUP and SUMIFS combined with IF statement but I think I'm missing something important because my conditions are not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap you lookup in IFERROR.
Search in your accounting data first, if it throws an error search in the survey data:

Example:
`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G2:G5,D2:E4,2,0),VLOOKUP(G2:G5,A2:B4,2,0))`

In this example:
`D2:E4` = accounting data,
`A2:B4` = survey data,
`G2:G5`= unique names from both data sets.
[image]

Comment: Thanks this works great! In my practical example I have 3 datasets, so I can also nest IFERROR formulas into one-another to get to the result. It even works perfectly with spill results!